# Duplicate with ESP32 Security with MKR1010/1500

Tags: ssl-certificate, esp32

How do I do the following with ArduinoBearSSL with an MKR1010/1500?

For ESP32 using

```
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>

  wifiClient.setCACert(AWS_CERT_CA); //Root CA
  wifiClient.setCertificate(CERT_CRT);  //client certificate
  wifiClient.setPrivateKey(CERT_PRIVATE);  //client key
```

For ThingStream PointPerfect does not allow the client to provide the key.

How would you duplicate this with ArduinoBearSSL?

Thanks

Bruce